# get records from current date mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am new at mongodb can someone help me to current my mongodb query,
I want to find date with current date from child object
my query is like

`db.users.find({"date.feeReminderDate": {"$gte":new Date("2017-06-28T18:30:00.000Z")} })`

Answer (score 1):

You can find record of current date/today's date by

```
db.users.find({"date.feeReminderDate": {$gte: ISODate("2017-07-03T00:00:00Z"), $lt: ISODate("2017-07-03T23:59:59Z")}});
```